# replacing values in vector, number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, date, vector

I have some strange problem with replacing values in data frame. I want to convert string to date format. I have to two this in two ways, because there are two formats of data.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

urlOnetWybory <- "http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/wybory-prezydenckie/xcnpc"
htmlOnetWybory <- html(urlOnetWybory)
nodes <- html_nodes(htmlOnetWybory, ".datePublished , .itemTitle")
text <- html_text(nodes)

dataRaw <- text[seq(1, length(text), 2)]

#"dzisiaj" = "today", "wczoraj"="yesterday"
data <- sapply(dataRaw, function(x){
  #converting string of the first type to data 
   stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "dzisiaj", as.character(Sys.Date()))
   stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "wczoraj", as.character(Sys.Date() - 1))
})

#indexes in dataRaw where there's a word "dzisiaj" or "wczoraj"
indeksDzis <- stri_detect_regex(dataRaw, "dzisiaj [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")
indeksWczo <- stri_detect_regex(dataRaw, "wczoraj [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")
#indexes for cells where date is in the second format.
indDoZmiany <- !(indeksDzis | indeksWczo)

#I get message here. Why? The length is the same.
data[indDoZmiany] <- strptime(data[indDoZmiany], "%d %b, %H:%M")
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Why do I get some list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIXlt has some traps because it is a list. Try this minimal example:

```
x <- strptime(c("15:40 12 mar", "12:58 11 mar"), "%d %b, %H:%M")
unclass(x)
```

Replace the last line with:

```
data[indDoZmiany] <- as.POSIXct( strptime(data[indDoZmiany], "%d %b, %H:%M"))
```

Comment: Hmm... but for example to one element in `data` `as.POSIXct(strptime(data[5], "%d %b, %H:%M"))` gives me the result `"2015-03-12 15:40:00 CET" ` but when I want to replace `data[5]` with this value `data[5] <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data[5], "%d %b, %H:%M"))` I get `"1426171200" ` So, still it is not a date ...

Comment: Because you are changing only a part of a vector. Vector can hold only one type.  Data is character. Either you change all values to date or some part with other characters.

Comment: for example: `as.character( as.POSIXct( strptime(data[indDoZmiany], "%d %b, %H:%M")))`